# Statistics finding p value from frozen dinners

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

[image]

For this question, for test statistic
$\frac{(sample\  mean - population\  mean)}{ (\frac{sample\ standard\  deviation} {\sqrt n})}$

$\frac{200.75 - 200}{(\frac{8.2586}{ \sqrt 12})}$

I have gotten $0.314590392$ for the test statistic

By using the free software from
https://www.r-project.org/

I have inputted the following using the r software

> $pt(0.314590392,11)$ where $11$ is $n - 1 (12-1)$ for $t$ distribution
>
> $p$ value of the test in $(a)-(b)$ is $0.6205204$

Are these the correct answers for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are testing $H_0: \mu = 200$ against the two-sided alternative
$H_a: \mu \ne 200.$ The null distribution of the $T$-statistic is Student's t
distribution with 11 degrees of freedom, and you have computed the observed value of the
$T$-statistic to be $T = .3146.$ Consider the PDF of $\mathsf{T}(11)$ plotted below.

[image]

For this two-sided test, the total P-value is the sum of the two areas
outside the vertical red lines. The solid red line is the observed value
of the t-statistic, but the dotted red line is at a value just as extreme
(far from $0$) in the opposite direction.

I'm glad to see you are using R. It is excellent software.
The R code you need in order to finish is one of the following two statements:

```
2*pt(-.3146, 11)
## 0.7589521
pt(-.3146,11) + (1 - pt(.3146,11))
## 0.7589521
```

Bear in mind that `pt` is the CDF of the t distribution.

---

Finally, because you have R, I will show you how to use it to do the test from scratch:

```
x = c(204, 202, 213, 198, 189, 200, 213, 206, 188, 193, 206, 197)
t.test(x, mu = 200)

        One Sample t-test

data:  x 
t = 0.3146, df = 11, p-value = 0.759
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 200 
95 percent confidence interval:
195.5027 205.9973 
sample estimates:
mean of x 
   200.75
```

Comment: That all makes sense thanks!!